# bs4 Tag element returning 'NoneType' when trying to extract information

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to extract information out of html code.

The following code functions correctly.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/chi/2019_roster.htm#'

#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
parsed_table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
for i, row in enumerate(parsed_table.find_all('tr')[2:]):
    dat = row.find('td', attrs={'data-stat':'player'})
    print(dat)
    
    name = dat.a
    print(type(name))
    print(name)
```

This returns a list as expected

e.g.

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<a href="/players/J/JackEd01.htm">Eddie Jackson </a>
```

Since "name" is a Tag element for bs4, I would expect that I would be able to get returns from the following

```
name.get('href')
name.get_text()
```

However, every time I try to do so, I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute #Whatever attribute I'm requesting
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with `name.get()` which is working as intended.

In your iteration, there is a `row` where `dat.a` is `None`.

```
<class 'NoneType'>
None <tr><th class="left iz" data-stat="pos" scope="row"></th><td class="left" data-stat="player"><b>Defensive Starters</b></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="age"></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="experience"></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="gs"></td><td class="left iz" data-stat="stat_summary"></td><td class="left iz" data-stat="draft_info"></td></tr>
```

This is because this `row` does not contain an `<a></a>` field.

Simply add an `if statment` to check if `name` or `dat.a` is not `None`, then run `name.get()`

```
for i, row in enumerate(parsed_table.find_all('tr')[2:]):
    dat = row.find('td', attrs={'data-stat':'player'})

    name = dat.a
    if name:
        print(name.get('href'))
```

---

```
/players/T/TrubMi00.htm
/players/C/CoheTa00.htm
/players/G/GabrTa00.htm
/players/M/MillAn02.htm
/players/R/RobiAl02.htm
/players/H/HoltJ.01.htm
/players/L/LenoCh00.htm
/players/D/DaniJa01.htm
/players/W/WhitCo03.htm
/players/C/CowaRa00.htm
/players/M/MassBo00.htm
/players/R/RobeRo00.htm
/players/G/GoldEd00.htm
/players/N/NichBi00.htm
/players/M/MackKh00.htm
/players/T/TrevDa00.htm
/players/S/SmitRo07.htm
/players/F/FloyLe00.htm
/players/F/FullKy00.htm
/players/A/AmukPr00.htm
/players/A/AmukPr00.htm
/players/C/ClinHa00.htm
/players/C/ClinHa00.htm
/players/J/JackEd01.htm
>>>
```